# U-SQl declaring @variables as null

Tags: u-sql

I have a master table which I am ingesting data to from a couple of source tables which I am not joining.

One of the tables doesn't have one of the columns so I want to insert Nulls into this column with an 'insert into' statement. To do this, I am trying to create a `@missing_column` variable.

```sql
DECLARE @missing_column string IS NULL;  // This does not work.
```

How would you recommend doing this? I know I can write the words "NULL" as a string and insert it as that. But that would not work for a column if it decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`U-SQL` uses the C# type system, so you need to define types and assign values using the C# syntax.  This means you will need to use a nullable type and assign the correctly typed `null` values:

Because `string` is a nullable type already, you can simply use:

```
DECLARE @missing_column string = (string)null;
```

Though if you were trying to use a non-nullable type such as `int`, you would need to specify the nullable version in your variable and table column:

```
DECLARE @missing_column int? = (int?)null;
```

The official documentation on U-SQL `DECLARE` statements can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/variables/declare-variables).

---

Having re-read your question, for your specific example you should just be able to ignore the missing column in your `INSERT` statement.  This will assign the values from the source table where assigned and leave the additional, unspecified target column `null`.  To to this, you will obviously need to have a nullable type in the table column per what I have written above:

Master table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MasterTarget
(
  Col1 Int,
  Col2 string,    // string is already nullable
  Col3 DateTime?, // DateTime is not, so need to specify DateTime? that accepts null values
  INDEX clx_Col1 CLUSTERED(Col1 ASC)
)
DISTRIBUTED BY HASH(Col1);
```

All column data load:

```
@src1 =
    EXTRACT Col1 Int,
            Col2 string,
            Col3 DateTime
    FROM "/SourceFile1.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv();

INSERT INTO dbo.MasterTarget
(
  Col1,
  Col2,
  Col3
)
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3
FROM @src1;
```

Missing column data load:

```
@src2 =
    EXTRACT Col1 Int,
            Col2 string
    FROM "/SourceFile2.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv();

INSERT INTO dbo.MasterTarget
(
  Col1,
  Col2
)
SELECT Col1,
       Col2
FROM @src2;
```

Comment: The first part works great thanks :)
With the second way, how would it work if it was column 2 missing and not 3?

Comment: The exact same way...  Just reference the columns you are `INSERT`ing into in the same order as you are `SELECT`ing them.